# `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context

Tags: nested, django-rest-framework, serialization

I've already tried everything I could, but nothing works for me

My models:

```
model Parent():
    ...
model Child():
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                          related_name='children')
    ...
```

My Urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'parents', ParentViewSet, base_name="parents")
router.register(r'childs', ChildViewSet, base_name="childs")

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

My serializers:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="parent-detail", lookup_field='pk')
    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            ...
            'children')

    def get_children(self, obj):
        queryset = Child.objects.filter(owner=obj)
        children = ChildSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
        return children

class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="child-detail", lookup_field='pk')
    ...
```

My Viewsets:

```
class ParentViewSet(SerializerByActionMixin, LoggingMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = Parent.objects.all().prefetch_related('children').order_by('-date_joined')
serializers = {
    'default': ParentSerializer,
    'create': ParentCreateSerializer,
    'update': ParentUpdateSerializer,
}

class ChildViewSet(LoggingMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = Child.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
serializer_class = ChildSerializer
http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'head']
```

My problem:
    `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.
I read this, but don't understand where in my code paste this context.
Help please. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says, you'll need the request in the context:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def get_children(self, obj):
        queryset = Child.objects.filter(owner=obj)
        children = ChildSerializer(queryset, many=True, context=self.context).data
        return children
```

Comment: I was so close, tried to pass this parameter, but it's not that)) I just do not have words ... decision ... Just universal thanks to you!